# php:edit and delete

Tags: php, edit

I want to make a registration form page which also contains a table where we retrieve the data entered through the form into the database. The table also have edit and delete options so that we can later make any change. I saw an example, how to make such 'edit and delete' table. But I could not understand the code given below:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_REQUEST['s']))
    { 
        if($_REQUEST['s']=="m")
        {
            echo "Successfully deleted.";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['s']))
    { 
        if($_REQUEST['s']=="e")
        {
            echo "Successfully update.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Can you explain it's meaning, line by line?

Comment: "Success fully deleted" seems appropriate...

Comment: SO is not for basic questions like this. If you do not understand this code, you cannot read basic PHP and explaining it would not help.

Comment: @Johan Im not sure its for you to judge what is easy to understand and what is not.  I agree that for myself it is very straightforward however comments like yours don't make SO any better, id much rather people didn't make pointless comments.

Comment: @JonTaylor I think the issue is people get fed up trying to spoon feed others who have not even had the courtesy to do basic googling research etc. But I do take your point it does not really add value but neither does the question. I guess In an ideal world the question would be well thought out with links and refs and the answers would be coherent with examples and links as supporting refs.

Answer (score 2):

the code below doesn't make much sense.
If anything it should be re-written

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['s']))
{ 
    switch($_REQUEST['s'])
    {
        case "m":
            echo "Success fully deleted.";
            break;
        case "e":
            echo "Success fully update.";
            break;
    }
}
```

This code checks if "s" has been passed either as $_POST or $_GET variable, if it was s=m then display message, that entity was successfully deleted, if e, it was successfully updated.

In general, try using more verbose names of variables, and avoid $_REQUEST due to security implications

Comment: Is the isset really necessary?

Comment: @Alex Lunix: not if you can live with the warnings generated. in short: yes, it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST['s']`   ----> This will get the submit button name `<input type="submit" name="s" value="m" />`

m and e is the value of submit button

```
<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST['s'])) // to check if button is pressed or not  
{ if($_REQUEST['s']=="m")  //if m button is clicked
{ 
 //code for delete
echo "Success fully deleted.";
}}
 if(isset($_REQUEST['s']))  
{ if($_REQUEST['s']=="e")  // if e button is clicked
{
  //code for update into db
echo "Success fully update.";
}}
?>
```

Comment: thanx, but  what 's','m' and 'e' button stands for?

Comment: @user1373335 `s` is the variable name used in your form, it may be in the form of a button, a hidden input, a textfield or whatever input element, `m` and `e` are the values associated with the variable. You can use any name as long as it fits the naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['s'])) { // If a Requst "s" exists eq index.php?s=hello
     if($_REQUEST['s']=="m") {  // Now lets see what value the Request "s" has IF s=="m"
         echo "Success fully deleted."; // Output because s has the Value "m"
     }
    }
```

Fort better understanding just try this

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['s'])) { 
     if($_REQUEST['s']=="m") {  // Now lets see what value the Request "s" has IF s=="m"
         echo "Success fully deleted."; // Output because s has the Value "m"
     } else {
        echo "s is not equal 'm': s has the value ".$_REQUEST['s'];
     }
    } else {
      echo "i need the Request s to do something";
      echo "<pre>Requests i got: ".print_r($_REQUEST,1)."</pre>";
   }
```

Now try it by:

yourscript.php?s=m

yourscript.php?s=hello

yourscript.php